# ffmpeg/avconv crashes when video frame isn't expected size

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg, libav

I'm capturing my webcam using ffmpeg/avconv, but I keep running into this problem:

```
The v4l2 frame is 828212 bytes, but 829440 bytes are expected
```

And then it crashes. It should just skip that frame, not crash the entire application.
Does anyone know how to make it continue?

Comment: How exactly are you capturing it? Via commandline or programming yourself? What do you use – FFmpeg or libav or both? Which versions – the packaged Ubuntu ones or compiled from source? What version of Ubuntu? Can you give us the full command line output you get?

Comment: Indeed: via the command line. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, which has libav version 0.8.3-4:0.8.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1.

Comment: Command and complete console output is missing.